# why isn't my p tag centering within my two content divs

Tags: css

I have a paragraph in the two `divs` with classes of `.content1` and `.content2` and I cant get them to center within the `divs`. Does one know why this is?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pwnftkpk/6/)

Code:

```
.content1 p, .content2 p {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.02);
    max-width: 280.34px;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to put your paragraphs? And you need to put them side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see text is aligned into your div.
look at 2 images with align left and align center
[image]

[image]

Comment: it is in smaller screen sizes but it does look centered in full screen

Answer (score 0):

I see now I misread the question all those months ago. To center each paragrapah itself within its parent `div`, when it's wider than the `max-width` of the paragraph, you just need to add the `margin` property to the rule included in your question, setting `margin-left` & `margin-right` to `auto`, like so:

```
.content1>p,.content2>p{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.02);
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:280.34px;
}
```

<s>Your text is centred in those paragraphs. However, as the text in those paragrpahs is just the same string being repeated multiple times, at some sizes you'll end up with the text on every line of the paragraphs being identical, making the paragraphs appear to be justified rather than centred. In those cases, though, you can just about see the centring on the last line which doesn't end with a comma.</s>

To avoid any problems like this in the future, try using "[lorem ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/)" as placeholder text instead.